# How to get the change of Close price between today and yesterday?

Tags: php, mysql

I am a very newbie on php and sql.

This is how the database look like.

I want the changes of Close for everyday.

```
 // Quantity of rows

 $sql = mysql_query("SELECT Date, Close FROM stock");

 $range = mysql_num_rows($sql);

echo $range . "<br>";

// Getting the Change

$result2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

for($i=1;$i<$range+1;$i++){

    $dayChange = $result2[$i]-$result2[$i-1];

    echo $dayChange . "<br>";

}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYMke.jpg

Comment: Count is better achieved by `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM stock`. And you should add LIMITS to your query of there ary many result rows and add a paging mechanism.

Comment: @HerrSerker why is count better achieved by using count? Not arguing, just wondering why.

Comment: @AliTrixx If you have many result rows, it will slow down system, because all the rows must be send from MySQL server to the PHP process.

Comment: I can't get the changes showing on the browser, I dont know whats going on

Comment: [Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://php.net/mysql_connect). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. [Here is a good PDO tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Answer (score 0):

If there is no holiday then try this sql query:

```
SELECT id, sDate AS mDate, close, (
close - ( 
SELECT close
FROM stock
WHERE sDate = DATE_ADD( mDate, INTERVAL 1 
DAY ) )
) AS dayChange
```

Comment: There are trading days only. No Saturday and Sunday, No public holidays. Anymore help!? Thanks